# PC won't start after editing fstab

Tags: ubuntu, bootloader, fstab

I have a box with Intel P5LD2-X/1333 motherboard. I installed 2 GB RAM. The box was working as it should, no problems basically. I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on it.

After editing the fstab file, I tried to link a harddrive to my home folder, and when I rebooted, nothing happened.  Nothing....Or, the box starts, but will not pass BIOS POST; black screen, and nothing else. I also cannot access the BIOS to change the start order to USB for fixing the fstab.

I figured out what I did wrong in the fstab; I didn't specify what filesystem the disk was. I have tried to take out the RAM, disk one by one, and the graphic card. Nothing seems to do anything.  How do I get the system to power up so that I can access the BIOS and then fix the fstab?

Comment: If it doesn't POST, that's not caused by your `fstab` changes. That's most likely a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can repair your fstab by using the Ubuntu Live CD for your system.  It allows you to run a shell in which the system disk is mounted.  Then you can edit it and eliminate the problem.

Paraphrasing the advice given in Ubuntu's page, you would do something like this;

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
3. sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
4. sudo chroot /mnt
5. vi /etc/fstab
6. exit (from the chroot)
7. reboot without the Live CD

You can read more about Ubuntu Live CD here: [LiveCdRecovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)

Comment: If it fails to pass post that is a moot issue